# How to link fftw3 on a macOS using CMake?

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, g++, fftw

I have the following fftw3 header files under `/usr/local/include`:

[image: ffw3 header files including fftw3.h]

Further, I have the following fftw3 static libraries under `/usr/local/lib`:

[image: ffw3 libraries including libfftw3.a]

However, when I try to compile my file using cmake and running make afterwards, I get the following errors:

[image]

What I find particularly odd is that when compiling the individual `*.cpp` files, I get no error despite the fact that these files use fftw_malloc and other functionality from `fftw3.h`.

I'm using `gcc` and `g++` version `10.2.0`. I configure my CMake file using `cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-10 -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc-10`.

I configured fftw3 through the download on the fftw3 website and running `./configure`, `make`, `sudo make install` in that order. As mentioned before, the files seem to have been installed in the correct place. I also tried the same with homebrew and MacPorts and ended up with the same result.

I'm also using [findFFTW](https://github.com/egpbos/findFFTW). Without this, even the `*.cpp` files don't seem to compile properly. Further, even findFFTW claims to have found the FFTW3 library, giving the following output during the configuration of the make file:
`-- Found FFTW: /usr/local/include`

Finally, my target link libraries are set to the following in the CMake file:
`target_link_libraries(cartogram CGAL::CGAL Boost::program_options fftw3)`

Is there any way I can solve the error I get? (`ld: library not found for -lfftw3`)

Edit: On a side note, the exact same cmake file works perfectly find on Ubuntu, Linux!

Comment: The [FindFFTW.cmake](https://github.com/egpbos/findFFTW/blob/master/FindFFTW.cmake) explicitly document, that it sets `FFTW_LIBRARIES` variable to the list of libraries. So you need to use this variable for link with fftw: `target_link_libraries(cartogram ${FFTW_LIBRARIES})`.

Comment: Please note, that Stack Overflow discourages using **images** which just contain a **text**. Instead, copy-paste the text into the question post. See also [ask].

Comment: Thank you @Tsyvarev, I will keep in mind the rules for posting questions next time. I changed -lfftw3 to the variable link provided by findFFTW. However, I now run into another issue which states `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:` and has boost15program_options mentioned at many places!

Comment: Well, your new error is about boost and not about fftw.